# Square root of the product of consecutive natural numbers is irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers

Prove that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the number $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ is irrational.

My first move would be:

Let's assume that it's not, that it $\sqrt{n(n+1)} = \frac{a}{b}$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a,b$ are coprime. Then:
$$
n(n+1)=\frac{a^2}{b^2} \iff a^{2}=n(n+1)b^2
$$
I do not know how to continue this proof (I suppose that it is worth to notice that $n(n+1)$ is the divisor of $a^2$). Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hint: $n^2< n^2+n<(n+1)^2$

Comment: Not the most elegant proof, but one can prove the statement that the square root of a natural number that is not a perfect square is irrational. Then prove $n(n+1)$ cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: Do you happen to know the rational root theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $n(n+1)$ is a perfect square if $n=0$. So we assume $n\gt 0$.

Suppose to the contrary that $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ is rational. Then as in the OP there exist **relatively prime** integers $a$ and $b$, with $b$ positive, such that $a^2=n(n+1)b^2$.

If $b\gt 1$, then there is a prime $p$ that divides $b$. Then $p$ divides $a^2$, so $p$ divides $a$, contradicting the fact $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

Thus we must have $b=1$. Now we show that $n(n+1)$ cannot be a perfect square if $n\gt 0$. If $n^2+n$ is a perfect square, so is $4n^2+4n$. But $4n^2+4n=(2n+1)^2-1$, and the only two consecutive perfect squares are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: This shows the further result that $\sqrt{r}$ is rational if and only if $r$ is a perfect square, yeah? (In particular, your middle two paragraphs do, as they are non-specific to $r = n(n+1)$.)

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I didn't prove that in my answer because (a) I wanted to give only a hint and (b) I didn't want to prove more than the OP was asking. However, it is very simple. Indeed, if I were to go back being to undergraduate fresher (not that it was that long ago!) doing a basic number theory course, I'd probably use this to prove stuff like the claim that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $n(n+1)$ is even, so the right-hand side is even. Thus $a$ must be even, so write it as $a = 2 a'$ ($a'$ may or may not be even, but is an integer), giving $4 a'^2 = n(n+1) b^2$. What can you now say about $b$ or $n(n+1)$? Maybe write $N = n(n+1)$, and then write $N = 2^k l$ for integers $k$ and $l$.